# Create BevelBorder of certain width in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a Button like below using combination of Borders.

While using BorderFactory or Bevel classes, there is no option to give the width.

Is it possible to give width to BevelBorder in Java Swing?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you cannot set the width of a `BevelBorder`. A `BevelBorder` just draws two 1px lines per edge - one for the outer shadow and one for the inner shadow. Unfortunately, just calling `setStroke` wouldn't work, because on each corner one color would just overlap the other and it would come to other unpleasant visuals.

Also, what you seem to request isn't really a `BevelBorder`. It's a border with 5 color specifications: The top, right, bottom, left and line color. A `BevelBorder` doesn't have a line color and also doesn't have such color specifications.

I've made a class that extends `AbstractBorder` which should fit your requirements:

[image]

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;

public class AdvancedBevelBorder extends AbstractBorder {

    private Color topColor, rightColor, bottomColor, leftColor, lineColor;
    private int borderWidth;

    public AdvancedBevelBorder(Color topColor, Color rightColor, Color bottomColor, Color leftColor, Color lineColor,
            int borderWidth) {
        setTopColor(topColor);
        setRightColor(rightColor);
        setBottomColor(bottomColor);
        setLeftColor(leftColor);
        setLineColor(lineColor);
        setBorderWidth(borderWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);

        int h = height;
        int w = width;
        int bw = getBorderWidth();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.translate(x, y);

        Polygon topPolygon = createPolygon(new Point(0, 0), new Point(w, 0), new Point(w - bw, bw), new Point(bw, bw),
                new Point(0, 0));
        g2.setColor(getTopColor());
        g2.fill(topPolygon);
        g2.setColor(getLineColor());
        g2.draw(topPolygon);

        Polygon rightPolygon = createPolygon(new Point(w - 1, 0), new Point(w - 1, h), new Point(w - bw - 1, h - bw),
                new Point(w - bw - 1, bw), new Point(w - 1, 0));
        g2.setColor(getRightColor());
        g2.fill(rightPolygon);
        g2.setColor(getLineColor());
        g2.draw(rightPolygon);

        Polygon bottomPolygon = createPolygon(new Point(0, h - 1), new Point(w, h - 1), new Point(w - bw, h - bw - 1),
                new Point(bw, h - bw - 1), new Point(0, h - 1));
        g2.setColor(getBottomColor());
        g2.fill(bottomPolygon);
        g2.setColor(getLineColor());
        g2.draw(bottomPolygon);

        Polygon leftPolygon = createPolygon(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, h), new Point(bw, h - bw), new Point(bw, bw),
                new Point(0, 0));
        g2.setColor(getLeftColor());
        g2.fill(leftPolygon);
        g2.setColor(getLineColor());
        g2.draw(leftPolygon);

        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(getBorderWidth(), getBorderWidth(), getBorderWidth() + 1, getBorderWidth() + 1);
    }

    private Polygon createPolygon(Point... points) {
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        for (Point point : points) {
            polygon.addPoint(point.x, point.y);
        }
        return polygon;
    }

    public Color getTopColor() {
        return topColor;
    }

    public void setTopColor(Color topColor) {
        this.topColor = topColor;
    }

    public Color getRightColor() {
        return rightColor;
    }

    public void setRightColor(Color rightColor) {
        this.rightColor = rightColor;
    }

    public Color getBottomColor() {
        return bottomColor;
    }

    public void setBottomColor(Color bottomColor) {
        this.bottomColor = bottomColor;
    }

    public Color getLeftColor() {
        return leftColor;
    }

    public void setLeftColor(Color leftColor) {
        this.leftColor = leftColor;
    }

    public Color getLineColor() {
        return lineColor;
    }

    public void setLineColor(Color lineColor) {
        this.lineColor = lineColor;
    }

    public int getBorderWidth() {
        return borderWidth;
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    }

}
```

---

By the way, I made the component you can see in image with the following code:

```
AdvancedBevelBorder border = new AdvancedBevelBorder(new Color(120, 172, 220), new Color(55, 93, 128),
        new Color(73, 124, 169), new Color(150, 191, 229), new Color(36, 83, 126), 10);
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 60);
    }
};
panel.setBackground(new Color(91, 154, 212));
panel.setBorder(border);
```

Comment: In the image above,  I have created a button using the border class you provided. The border overlaps with the text inside. I think there is still codes to be fixed that arrange the preferred size of Button according to the size of Border.

Comment: there is still some problem with "edge line", when used in a button the rightmost and the bottommost line are disappeared

Comment: @Barun Should be fixed. Sorry for the bugs, I hope I didn't forget anything else.